# Styling pg_tileserv pbf in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, vector-tiles, pg-tileserv

I am having a ton of trouble styling my pbf tile service rendered from pg_tileserv in a leaflet map.

here is my code

```
L.vectorGrid.protobuf(http://localhost:7800/data_oh.parcel/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf, {
        interactive: true,
        rendererFactory: L.svg.tile,
          vectorTileLayerStyles: {
            parcel: {
            fillColor: "yellow",
            fill: true,
            color: "red"
                }
          }
    }).addTo(map);
```

it comes up standard blue.

now if I take the suggestions of [Styling GeoServer pbf vector tiles in Leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256888/styling-geoserver-pbf-vector-tiles-in-leaflet)

and run

```
    var vectorTileOptions = {
        interactive: true,
        // pane: "OverlayPane",
        vectorTileLayerStyles: {
          parcel: {
            fillColor: "yellow",
            fill: true,
            color: "red"
         }
        }
      };

L.vectorGrid.protobuf("http://localhost:7800/data_oh.parcel/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf",vectorTileOptions).on('click',function(e) {
    console.log(e.layer);
    L.DomEvent.stop(e);
}).addTo(map);
```

it doesnt correctly change the color and in those directions I don't see anything that could help me change this

[image]

the actual datalayername is `data_oh.parcel` but I cannot write it like that in the vector grid function because it will give me an error with the `.`

not sure what to do here, ive found other examples which have not helped me

[Styling polygons in a map tile PBF file in Leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348158/styling-polygons-in-a-map-tile-pbf-file-in-leaflet)
https://eox.at/2020/01/vector-tiles-with-dynamically-updated-style-in-leaflet-lpvis/

Comment: Try putting your layer name which contains `.` into quotes: `'data_oh.parcel'`.

Comment: @TomazicM nope got an error

Comment: Any possibility of trying your vector tile layer?

Comment: unfortunately its on my local so unless I open up my ports...no

Comment: oh wait that worked! I was connecting to the wrong DB when I tried your suggestion @TomazicM thanks feel free to make it an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `vectorTileLayerStyles` option is a JS object (JSON), property names can be put in quotes when containing characters that can otherwise be interpreted as some kind of delimiter.

So solution in this case is simply to put layer name property in quotes:

```
var vectorTileOptions = {
  interactive: true,
  vectorTileLayerStyles: {
    'data_oh.parcel': {
      fillColor: "yellow",
      fill: true,
      color: "red"
   }
  }
};
```

Comment: I'm trying to take what you showed me with multiple layers and function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65146183/javascript-force-insert-string-into-js-object-json-leaflet-vectortiles/65146345#65146345 would be awesome if you could help me out here!

Comment: If you don't get answer on StackOverflow, remove question there and post it here.