# How to find vector tile URLs from GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, vector-tiles, wmts, tile-map-service

I have spent a lot of time trying to figure out the correct WMTS call to make to my GeoServer to get vector tiles (from my Leaflet web app), which I eventually found from the GetCapabilities: `http://localhost:8000/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=getcapabilities`, where I was able to Ctrl+F to find ".pbf" which led me to this line:

```
<ResourceURL format="application/json" resourceType="TileJSON" template="localhost:8000/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts/rest/city:roads/{style}/tilejson/pbf?format=application/json"/>
```

Following the "template" value given here, it gave me 2 new URLs:
`http://localhost:8000/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts/rest/city:roads/{style}/EPSG:4326/EPSG:4326:{z}/{y}/{x}?format=application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile`, while the other URL just had EPSG:900913 instead of 4326.

My process was similar for the TMS server to find something with the format, but then I saw that the additional `/{z}/{x}/{-y}.pbf` values needed to be added from [this post online](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/256888/220902):

```
http://localhost:8000/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/city:roads@EPSG:900913@pbf/{z}/{x}/{-y}.pbf
```

How are you properly supposed to find the URLs to WMTS and TMS services usually? I feel like I just stumbled upon this. New to this area.

Answer (score 1):

For any OGC service you are correct to look in the `getCapabilites` response, it probably also helps to read the standards if you need to know more. A well designed client however should "know" all this and work it out for you.

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/api/6.4.1/tile-url-templates.html :

> {x}   The index of the tile along the map’s x axis according to Spherical Mercator projection. If the value is 0, the tile’s left edge corresponds to the 180th meridian west. If the value is 2z−1, the tile’s right edge corresponds to the 180th meridian east.

> {y}   The index of the tile along the map’s y axis according to Spherical Mercator projection. If the value is 0, the tile’s tile edge corresponds to arctan(sinh(π)), or approximately 85.0511 degrees north. If the value is 2z−1, the tile’s bottom edge corresponds to −arctan(sinh(π)), or approximately 85.0511 degrees south. The y axis is inverted if the options parameter contains MGLTileSourceOptionTileCoordinateSystem with a value of MGLTileCoordinateSystemTMS.

So if you have langitude and longitude you can calculate x and y as follows (python):

```
x = int((lon + 180) / 360 * (2 ** z))
y = int((1 - (math.log(math.tan(math.radians(lan)) + 1 / math.cos(math.radians(lan)))) / math.pi) / 2 * (2 ** z))
```

while `z` is you zoom level